# How to add manually or automatically a missing y-label on y-axis which is not uniform towards other regular intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, imshow

I have the following figure :

[image: colormap with starting value not showing on y-axis]

I made it by the following Python script :

```
# Colormap plot
im = ax.imshow(np.log10(np.abs(matrixCl_der_transposed)), extent = [1e-8, 1e-1, 10, 5000], origin='lower',\
               aspect = 'auto', interpolation = 'none', cmap = 'viridis')

# Increase space between x-axis and x-label
ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', which = 'major', pad = 15) 

# Add lower multipole l = 10
y_label_list = ['10', '1000', '2000', '3000', '4000', '5000']
ax.set_yticks = [10, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
ax.set_yticklabels(y_label_list)

# Log scal for step
plt.xscale('log')

# Title 
plt.title('$\log_{10}|(C_{l}\')|$ of '+paramLatexArray[idParam]+' at $z$ = '+\
           str(zrange[idRedshift]), fontsize = 24, pad = 25) 

# Lebels on axis
plt.xlabel('step', fontsize = 20) 
plt.ylabel('$l$ multipole', fontsize = 20) 
plt.xticks(fontsize = 20) 
plt.yticks(fontsize = 20) 
plt.grid()


# Color bar 
clb = plt.colorbar(im)
clb.ax.set_title('$\log_{10}|(C_{l}\')|$', fontsize = 20, pad = 12) 
clb.ax.tick_params(labelsize = 16) 
tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=15)
clb.locator = tick_locator
clb.update_ticks()
```

As you can see, I tried to add explicitly  the lower value (origin which is equal to `10`) of y-axis, by doing :

```
# Add lower multipole l = 10
y_label_list = ['10', '1000', '2000', '3000', '4000', '5000']
ax.set_yticks = [10, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
ax.set_yticklabels(y_label_list)
```

But unfortunalety, this lower value doesn't appear on left bottom of the plot. Values `1000`, `2000`, `3000`, `4000` and `5000` are shown but not for `10` value.

Does `extent = [1e-8, 1e-1, 10, 5000]` option of `imshow` cause this issue ?

How can I automatically add this lower value?

Comment: You destroyed the `set_yticks` method by assigning a list to it instead of calling it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ,  thanks but how to call   it : directly by doing `ax.set_yticks(10, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000)` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, you destroyed the `set_yticks` method by assigning a list to it instead of calling it. Also mind that the tick positions should not be strings.

```
y_label_list = [10, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
ax.set_yticks(y_label_list)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_label_list)
```

Comment: Thanks,  is there a way to use the instruction `plt.yticks(fontsize = 20) ` with your solution ? I would like to use with : `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` ? I mean without using `ax = plt.gca()` ?

Comment: `ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=20)`?

Comment: Am I obliged to use `ax = plt.gca()`to   handle axis labels ? Can't I directly use a `plt.ax.set_yticks(....)` ?

Comment: You can use `plt.yticks(...)` or `plt.gca().set_yticks(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Like @ImportanceOfBeingErnest commented, `set_yticks` is a function, not a property. You should call it and pass to it a list of labels, like so:

```
y_label_list = ['10', '1000', '2000', '3000', '4000', '5000']
ax.set_yticks(y_label_list)
```

[Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html)